# Compile-time check struct with function pointers to validate assignments

Tags: c, gcc, struct, visual-studio-2013, function-pointers

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

I have a namespace-style struct setup, filled with just function pointers. These are provided in the header file like so:

```
typedef struct {

    int32_t(*const event_construct)(struct sync_event* evt);
    int32_t(*const event_destroy)(struct sync_event* evt);
    int32_t(*const event_set)(struct sync_event* evt);
    int32_t(*const event_wait)(struct sync_event* evt);

} namespace_sync;

extern namespace_sync const sync;
```

and then in the relevant source file, after all the function implementations:

```
...

namespace_sync const sync = {
    sync_event_construct,
    sync_event_destroy,
    sync_event_set,
    sync_event_wait
};
```

Say I want to add an extra function not at the end; I add it to the struct and source file, but forget to assign it. Because the function declarations match, a warning isn't generated for it, and the compiler (at least in this example, vs2013) doesn't provide a hint that there's an issue.

I've got compile-time assertion checks available, but not sure if I can verify this particular aspect, since the struct size is accurate. If vs2013 can't work with it - I'm aware it's an abysmal C compiler(!) - the newest versions of gcc will also be used, so I could limit the functionality to one compiler.

Comment: Change the name of the struct when you change its definition (e.g. make it `namespace_sync_2`). Then the compiler will show you everything that needs to be updated.

Comment: Doesn't work. Visual Studio and GCC 4.9.1 have no problem with it (even with 0 assignments, no complaints are made)

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my suggestion? If there is no longer a name defined `namespace_sync`, then the code `namespace_sync const sync = {`... must give a compilation error.

Comment: Ok, but then it's impractical - I'm less likely to remember to change the name of a struct than to add a new functions assignment! In addition, the error wouldn't point to the fact the struct needs updating, only that it's invalid - and we all have bad days where we'd forget..

Comment: I didn't follow any of that sorry. My suggestion allows you to sit down and have the compiler point out all instances where the error you describe might be happening, so that you can go through and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

One solution going forward would be to use designated initializers:

```
namespace_sync const sync = {
    .event_construct = sync_event_construct,
    .event_destroy = sync_event_destroy,
    .event_set = sync_event_set,
    .event_wait = sync_event_wait
};
```

Any unlisted members will default to null pointers.

I would advise to not add members into the middle of a struct, because it is difficult to be sure that you have correctly updated any code that was relying on the old struct layout. However, if you really do want to do this, then one way to have the compiler indicate to you where all the uses of the struct are is to change the struct name:

```
typedef struct {
    // ...
} namespace_sync_2;
```

Then the code `namespace_sync const sync` will cause a compilation error. This alerts you to the fact that this piece of code requires a code review to make sure that it will work correctly with the new struct layout.